# velocity log file not writing/rolling

Tags: apache, log4j, velocity, resin

My issue seems peculiar. First i'll explain my setup. I'm using CentOS with Apache and Resin service. Thing is my application log seems to work perfectly fine configured with log4j but velocity log is not working (logger name = org.apache.velocity).

My local environment with the above specified settings works great (incuding the velocity log).

However in my dev environment configured with the same environment only the velocity log fails to roll or write any data.

I have very limited access to the dev environment and am unable to simulate this issue in the similar local env. hence unable to find the root cause or a solution to this.

Any help/suggestions on this would be greatly appreciated..

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was an issue with a corrupted jar file on the dev end...fixed now... hope this serves some help to any person with similar fate...